# Graph not generating currently in Excel using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, graph

I want to generate a graph with the following data

[image]format as shown

I wish to generate the graph using just 2 columns out of all shown above, Column A(Date & Time) & Column B(Profit). Column A has specific Custom type: dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm.

Below is erroneous graph getting generated:

[image]

Expected format of the graph is as below:
[image]

Below in the code I am using:

```
$wsChart = $wb.WorkSheets.item(1) 
$wsChart.activate()

$wsChart.UsedRange.EntireColumn.Autofit()
$DataforFirstChart = $wsChart.Range("A:B")
$chart = $wsChart.Shapes.AddChart().Chart

$chart.SetSourceData($DataforFirstChart)

$chart.HasTitle = $true

$chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Test Report"
# Save the sheet
$wb.Save()  

$wb.close() 
$excelapp.Quit()
```

Comment: try `$wsChart.Range("A1:B10")`  ?

Comment: yeah, i tried that not working.

Comment: Problem is with that formatted date timestamp. When i change it to date type like 04/10/2017(with increasing days), it just work fine. But in my case interval is of 15 minutes, that is creating some problem due to some reason.